# Why do i need prefix openssl with winpty on windows bash?

Tags: windows, bash, openssl, git-bash

Why do i need prefix openssl with winpty on windows bash?

Why does command

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
```

hangs and doesn't respond

while

```
winpty openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
```

is working fine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bash` from Git for Windows uses `mintty`. `mintty` cannot present itself as console to `openssl` but `winpty` can because it does the required conversions. Learn the details at [Git for Windows FAQ](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ#some-native-console-programs-dont-work-when-run-from-git-bash-how-to-fix-it).

Comment: adding to the answer: winpty runs an actual windows console window in the background

Answer (score 5):

> winpty is a Windows software package providing an interface similar to
>   a Unix pty-master for communicating with Windows console programs. The
>   package consists of a library (libwinpty) and a tool for Cygwin and
>   MSYS for running Windows console programs in a Cygwin/MSYS pty

Because you try to run native openssl in *not-native* shell, you have to have interface of `winpty`

Comment: Could you please explain more? I didn't really get it

Comment: @Patlatus native OpenSSL can't be run in a not-native shell.

Comment: Thanks all!  It might improve the answer to give some detailed description of a "_native shell_".